# SQL 'overlaps' only get dates between start and end (not include start and end dates)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I use this query to get objects overlaps the period between "**start_date**" and "**end_date**", moreover, I would like get the objects with dates **end on start_date** and objects **begin on end_date**.

I use

```
where("(start_date, end_date) overlaps (date ?, date ?), start_date, end_date"
```

But the objects has dates **<=start_date** or **>=end_date** is **not** get.

This 'overlaps' only gets objects has dates **start_date< dates< end_date**, not "=".

For example, start_date='2011/2/1', end_date='2011/3/31'. objects has date ends on '2011/2/1' or start on '2011/3/31' will not be get, only dates between '2011/2/1' and '2011/3/31' will get. how to includes objects which holds date ends on the start_date and start on the end_date?

**----------------------Edit----------------------------**

I try to use:

```
where("(start_date, end_date) overlaps (date ?, date ?), start_date-1.day, end_date+1.day"
```

to solve the issue, but when I do like above, if start_date='2011/2/1', end_date='2011/3/31', then objects holds '2011/1/31' also returns which is supposed should not be get.

Answer (score 1):

On the SQL side, you want to generate something like this, assuming

- S1, E1 are the start and end dates of
  the first range,
- S2, E2 are the start and end dates of
  the second range,
- none of S1, E1, S2, E2 are NULL

  WHERE (S1, E1) OVERLAPS (S2, E2) OR (E1 = S2) OR (E2 = S1)

You need both "OR" clauses, because in the general case you don't know which range is earlier.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
where("start_date >= ? and end_date <= ?", start_date.beginning_of_day, end_date.end_of_day)
```

that should include all from start_date to end_date ;-) hope it helps!

Comment: u didn't get the date range u wanted?

Comment: What I'd like to have is the objects holds dates from '2011/1/1' to '2011/2/1' will return if set the start_date='2011/2/1' and end_date='2011/3/31' , That's why I use 'Overlaps'

Comment: My poor English expression, sorry. The problem is 'overlaps' does not include the objects with dates end on start_date and objects begin on end_date. I try to solve it by use start_date-1.day and end_day+1.day, but it returns objects with start_date-2.day also.

Comment: nah it's my bad, anyway probably u can use the same way as i did, as in u don't use start_date - 1.day and end_date + 1.day, but u use start_date.beginning_of_day, and end_date.end_of_date instead. it should work =)

Answer (score 0):

Just assuming a table Details and having attributes(including date),suppose i want info from two specific dates as from start_date to end_date.

so,
Details.**where(["date between ? and ? ",start_date,end_date])** 
will give the required info including start and end dates.Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you, but , again, what I would like to have is not get objects from a exact time period. What I'd like to have is the objects holds dates from '2011/1/1' to '2011/2/1' will be return if I set the start_date='2011/2/1' and end_date='2011/3/31' in the query, That's why I use 'Overlaps'